# How to convert from String to SealedObject?

Tags: java, sockets

I have a SealedObject containing some information. Before being sent over to the server, I convert it to a string. Once the information arrives at the server end, I have a key to decrypt the encrypted information, only if it's a SealedObject though, I wish to convert the string sent back to a SealedObject on the server side. Is that possible? Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Which library are you referring to using `SealedObject`?

Comment: javax.crypto.SealedObject

Comment: Why are you converting binary data to a String? String is not a container for binary data. Remove that step and the problem disappears.

Comment: Which outputstream would I use as I can't just send sealedobject as it is, would I need to use objectoutputstream?

Comment: Certainly, why not?

Comment: I used an ObjectOutputStream to output the SealedObject, I used the function out.writeObject(sealedObject); How would I decrypt this in the other side?

Comment: Err, `ObjectInputStream.readObject()`?

Comment: I'm using RSA and SealedObject, is there another way to decrypt with private key without having to convert to SealedObject?

Comment: Changing SealedObject to bytes, testing to see if that would be better.

Comment: I have figured it out. Everything works now